# Could you please help me analyze the grammar/structure of this sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> "They have betrayed that puzzling dictum “To thine own self be true,” so often quoted approvingly as if it represented the wisdom of Shakespeare rather than the hot air of Polonius. ” **What’s to become of me? What’s to become of me?”** wails Eliza Doolittle, realizing her middling dilemma."

I am particularly confused about the expression "what is to become of me." Does it mean "what I would become?" If it is, then why the sentence would be structured like that?

Comment: Lexico explains this clearly.

Comment: Is to become = will become. Check unnecessary quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I am still confused about "become of me"

Answer (score 1):

"What will become of me?" Is a rather dated way of saying "What will my financial and other circumstances be?". When it was used widely it was usually an indication that the speaker was facing a serious collapse of their fortune, probably leading to destitution. For instance "If Iose the farm what will become of me?"; "Now my husband has died what will  become of me?" and so on.

Eliza Doolittle's problem, in both the play Pygmalion and the derived musical My Fair Lady was that, although she had been able to scrape a living as a flower girl before being used as an experimental subject by Higgins, she was, after that process, no longer satisfied with lower class life but did not have the means to live the comfortable middle class life she had been introduced to.